# How do I loop this in XDocument using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've table and td value as below code

```
foreach (var descendant in xmlDoc.Descendants("thead"))           
{             
    var title = descendant.Element("td1 style=background:#cccccc").Value; 
}
```

Assume I've below thead in the table

```
<thead>
<tr align="center" bgcolor="white">
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">Start</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">A</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">B</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">C</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">D</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">E</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">F</td1> 
  <td1 style="background:#cccccc">G</td1> 
 </tr>
  </thead>
```

I need to get all td1 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `Element` is incorrect - you just pass in a *name*, not the whole content of an element declaration.

If you want all `td1` elements, you want something like:

```
foreach (var descendant in xmlDoc.Descendants("thead"))
{
    foreach (var title in descendant.Element("tr")
                                    .Elements("td1")
                                    .Select(td1 => td1.Value))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or if you don't actually need anything from the `thead` elements:

```
foreach (var title in descendant.Descendants("thead")
                                .Elements("tr")
                                .Elements("td1")
                                .Select(td1 => td1.Value))
{
    ...
}
```

(Do you really mean `td1` rather than `td` by the way?)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky If i give td the code is displaying as table. so i've given td1. Actually i need to loop entire table based on the td values in xdocument. That is what I'm plan to write the code

Comment: @user1990395: Yes, it would display as a table - because presumably you're in a `table` HTML element. It's really not clear what you're trying to do, but it's a bad idea to create your own HTML tags like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I know it was table only. I was trying to loop the table using xdocument and assign the values to rest of the tr list based on the first tr header list.

Comment: @user1990395: My point is that creating a document which is "a bit like HTML, but not quite" sounds like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: +1 also correct solution. And agree, that creating something 'like html' is a bad idea :)

Comment: @JonSkeet hmmmm its ok mate.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `td1` elements, then in this case you can select them directly:

```
var titles = xdoc.Descendants("td1").Select(td => (string)td);
```

Or you can use XPath

```
var titles = from td in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//thread/tr/td1")
             select (string)td;
```

**NOTE** if you are going to parse html documents, then better consider to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet).

Comment: Note that your first version will find *all* td1 elements, not only those under thead.

Comment: @JonSkeet yep, wrote that based on sample xml above